# Problem with deleting photos in Dropbox

Tags: connection

I can't delete the photos from my full dropbox. It says to retry because I'm not connected. What is the problem and how can I get more free dropbox space

Answer (score 1):

**Q1:** I can't delete the photos from my full dropbox. It says to retry because I'm not connected.

You can delete it by:

- Signing in into the Dropbox website
- Click on the empty space to the right of the file's name to select
  it. (Clicking on the file name or icon will open the file as a
  preview)
- Press Delete from the action bar across the top of the file browser

**Q2:** How can I get more free drop box space?

You can earn free space by:

- Referring your friends, family, and coworkers to Dropbox
- To refer friends you'll need to sign in to your account, click Settings, and then click "invite your friends."
- Completing their "Get Started" guide
- Connecting your Facebook and Twitter accounts to Dropbox, and follow us on Twitter
- Link Dropbox with your Mailbox for iOS account